# Access: ‘Cannot group on fields selected with '*'.’

Tags: sql, oracle, count, ms-access-2007, sql-like

I am trying to select rows based on various `like` criterias, and have written the following function:

```
SELECT *,
COUNT(YRKE) AS Antall_med_yrket
FROM [T8 kopi (til sletting) av T7 3]
WHERE  YRKE like "*læge*"
    OR YRKE like "*præst*"
    OR YRKE like "*Lærer*"
    OR YRKE like "*lærer*"
    OR YRKE like "*chef.*"
    OR YRKE like "*mester*"
    OR YRKE like "*Portner*"
    OR YRKE like "*portner*"
    ⋮
    OR YRKE like "*fuglefanger*"
    ⋮
    OR YRKE like "*Glasanfanger*"
GROUP BY YRKE
;
```

The ‘⋮’ denotes omitted lines. What I want to do, is show all rows where the denoted words occur, and show the count for hits on these words. Example output:

```
ID   NAVN           YRKE                      Antall_med_yrket
 1   Ole Olsen      Fuglefanger               3
 2   Per Olsen      Skogbruger (Fuglefanger)  3
 3   Olav Krogh     Fængselslæge              1
 4   Kristen Persen Gaardbruger (Fuglefanger) 3
 5   Per Kristensen Fængselsdirecteur         1
```

However, when I add the `COUNT` line, I get the error message as showed in the title. Removing the line gives the output of all rows as desired, but of course without the count. What am I doing wrong?

I am using MS Access 2007 on Oracle.

Comment: hi, not sure how MS Access handles things, but in oracle the % is the wildcard to use with LIKE statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct.  The following *should* work:

```
SELECT YRKE, COUNT(YRKE) AS Antall_med_yrket
FROM [T8 kopi (til sletting) av T7 3]
WHERE  YRKE like "*læge*"
    OR YRKE like "*præst*"
    OR YRKE like "*Lærer*"
    OR YRKE like "*lærer*"
    OR YRKE like "*chef.*"
    OR YRKE like "*mester*"
    OR YRKE like "*Portner*"
    OR YRKE like "*portner*"
    ⋮
    OR YRKE like "*fuglefanger*"
    ⋮
    OR YRKE like "*Glasanfanger*"
GROUP BY YRKE;
```

In a SQL aggregation query, the columns in the `SELECT` generally need to be one of the following:

- Explicitly mentioned in the `GROUP BY`.
- An expression formed by columns explicitly mentioned in the `GROUP BY`.
- The arguments to aggregation functions, such as `SUM()` or `MIN()`.

Note:  there is one exception allowed in some databases (essentially, you can say `GROUP BY id` and use the other columns when `id` is unique).  However, neither MS Access nor Oracle support that functionality.

Comment: So the reason my query failed, was that I didn't specifically list the column in my select line?

Comment: @CannedMan . . . The reason is because you included `*`.